# Alloy UI carousel

Tags: user-interface, carousel, alloy-ui

I am using Alloy UI for my slideshow and it works great. I have 2 issues.

How can I stop the slideshow after the last slide?
On click of Replay button, how do I replay the carousel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `detach` method.
Here is a [link](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Carousel.html#method_detach).

Answer (score 0):

To stop the slideshow on last image, you can set `circular` to `false` (default is `true`).
See: [Alloy Carousel API](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Carousel.html#attr_circular)